# Creating PrimeFaces metergauge chart without @PostConstruct annotation

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I need to retrieve data from spring jpa data to an managed bean class, which creates an `MeterGaugeChartView`. When I call the values from injected Spring bean within an `@PostConstruct` method I get `java.lang.NullPonterException`. When I remove the annotation, then I get the error below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
```

Below is my code and the full stack...

```
package ch.business.quickline.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.chart.MeterGaugeChartModel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ch.business.quickline.viewservice.MitarbeiterGlobalService;

@ManagedBean
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class MeterGaugeChartView implements Serializable {

    private MeterGaugeChartModel masterBewertungenIndividual;
    private MeterGaugeChartModel selbstBewertungenIndividual;
    private MeterGaugeChartModel masterBewertungenGlobal;
    private MeterGaugeChartModel selbstBewertungenGlobal;

    @ManagedProperty("#{mitarbeiterGlobalService}")
    private MitarbeiterGlobalService mitarbeiterGlobalService;

    public void init() {
        createMeterGaugeModels();
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getMasterBewertungenIndividual() {
        return masterBewertungenIndividual;
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getSelbstBewertungenIndividual() {
        return selbstBewertungenIndividual;
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getMasterBewertungenGlobal() {
        return masterBewertungenGlobal;
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getSelbstBewertungenGlobal() {
        return selbstBewertungenGlobal;
    }

    private MeterGaugeChartModel initMeterGaugeModel() {
        List<Number> intervals = new ArrayList<Number>() {{
                add(1);
                add(2);
                add(3);
                add(4);
                add(5);
            }
        };

        return new MeterGaugeChartModel(5, intervals);
    }

    public void createMeterGaugeModels() {
        masterBewertungenIndividual = initMeterGaugeModel();
        //masterBewertungenIndividual.setTitle("Masterbewertungen");
        masterBewertungenIndividual.setGaugeLabel("Skill");
        masterBewertungenIndividual.setValue(mitarbeiterGlobalService.getMasterBewertungIndividualAverage());

        selbstBewertungenIndividual = initMeterGaugeModel();
        //selbstBewertungenIndividual.setTitle("Selbstbewertungen");
        selbstBewertungenIndividual.setGaugeLabel("Interesse");
        selbstBewertungenIndividual.setValue(mitarbeiterGlobalService.getSelbstBewertungIndividualAverage());

        masterBewertungenGlobal = initMeterGaugeModel();
        //masterBewertungenGlobal.setTitle("Masterbewertungen");
        masterBewertungenGlobal.setGaugeLabel("Skill");
        masterBewertungenGlobal.setValue(mitarbeiterGlobalService.getMasterBewertungGlobalAverage());

        selbstBewertungenGlobal = initMeterGaugeModel();
        //selbstBewertungenGlobal.setTitle("Selbstbewertungen");
        selbstBewertungenGlobal.setGaugeLabel("Interesse");
        selbstBewertungenGlobal.setValue(mitarbeiterGlobalService.getSelbstBewertungGlobalAverage());
    }
}
```

```
package ch.business.quickline.viewservice;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ch.business.quickline.domain.MitarbeiterSkill;
import ch.business.quickline.service.MitarbeiterService;
import ch.business.quickline.service.MitarbeiterSkillService;

@ManagedBean(name = "mitarbeiterGlobalService")
@Component
@ApplicationScoped
public class MitarbeiterGlobalService {

    @Autowired
    private MitarbeiterService mitarbeiterService;
    @Autowired
    private MitarbeiterSkillService mitarbeiterSkillService;

    private BigDecimal masterBewertungIndividualAverage;
    private BigDecimal selbstBewertungIndividualAverage;
    private Double masterBewertungGlobalAverage;
    private Double selbstBewertungGlobalAverage;

    public void init() {
        masterBewertungIndividualAverage = mitarbeiterService.findByMitarbeiterId(1).getMitarbeiterMasterBewertungDurchschnitt();
        selbstBewertungIndividualAverage = mitarbeiterService.findByMitarbeiterId(1).getMitarbeiterSelbstBewertungDurchschnitt();
        masterBewertungGlobalAverage = retrieveMasterBewertungGlobalAverage();
        selbstBewertungGlobalAverage = retrieveSelbstBewertungGlobalAverage();
    }

    public BigDecimal getMasterBewertungIndividualAverage() {
        return masterBewertungIndividualAverage;
    }

    public void setMasterBewertungIndividualAverage(BigDecimal masterBewertungIndividualAverage) {
        this.masterBewertungIndividualAverage = masterBewertungIndividualAverage;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSelbstBewertungIndividualAverage() {
        return selbstBewertungIndividualAverage;
    }

    public void setSelbstBewertungIndividualAverage(
            BigDecimal selbstBewertungIndividualAverage) {
        this.selbstBewertungIndividualAverage = selbstBewertungIndividualAverage;
    }

    public Double getMasterBewertungGlobalAverage() {
        return masterBewertungGlobalAverage;
    }

    public void setMasterBewertungGlobalAverage(Double masterBewertungGlobalAverage) {
        this.masterBewertungGlobalAverage = masterBewertungGlobalAverage;
    }

    public Double getSelbstBewertungGlobalAverage() {
        return selbstBewertungGlobalAverage;
    }

    public void setSelbstBewertungGlobalAverage(Double selbstBewertungGlobalAverage) {
        this.selbstBewertungGlobalAverage = selbstBewertungGlobalAverage;
    }

    public Double retrieveMasterBewertungGlobalAverage() {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (MitarbeiterSkill skill : mitarbeiterSkillService.findAll()) {
            sum = sum + skill.getMasterBewertung();
        }

        return sum / mitarbeiterSkillService.findAll().size();
    }

    public Double retrieveSelbstBewertungGlobalAverage() {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (MitarbeiterSkill interest : mitarbeiterSkillService.findAll()) {
            sum = sum + interest.getSelbstBewertung();
        }

        return sum / mitarbeiterSkillService.findAll().size();
    }
}
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

      <ui:composition template="/templates/default/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <ui:insert>
                <div class="ui-grid">
                    <div class="ui-grid-row">
                        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                            <p:chart type="metergauge" model="#{meterGaugeChartView.masterBewertungenGlobal}" style="width:400px;height:250px" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                            <p:chart type="metergauge" model="#{meterGaugeChartView.selbstBewertungenGlobal}" style="width:400px;height:250px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
                    <div class="ui-grid-row">
                        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                            <p:dataList value="#{rankingDataList.mitarbeiterMasterBewertungRangliste}" var="mitarbeiter" type="ordered">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Top Mitarbeiter nach Masterbewertung
                                </f:facet>
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterVorname}
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterNachname}:
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterMasterBewertungDurchschnitt}
                            </p:dataList>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                            <p:dataList value="#{rankingDataList.mitarbeiterSelbstBewertungRangliste}" var="mitarbeiter" type="ordered">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Top Mitarbeiter nach Selbstbewertung
                                </f:facet>
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterVorname}
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterNachname}:
                                #{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterSelbstBewertungDurchschnitt}
                            </p:dataList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ui:insert>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

```
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:skillmanager' did not find a matching property.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Jan 28 2015 15:51:10 UTC
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         7.0.59.0
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Linux
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            3.13.0-24-generic
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_40-b25
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/fanatik/apache-tomcat-7.0.59
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/fanatik/apache-tomcat-7.0.59
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/fanatik/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/endorsed
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 706 ms
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFORMATION: validateJarFile(/home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/skillmanager/WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.1-b04.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMATION: TLD skipped. URI: http://mojarra.dev.java.net/mojarra_ext is already defined
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMATION: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMATION: TLD skipped. URI: 
        http://java.sun.com/jsf/html
     is already defined
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFORMATION: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [ch.business.quickline.config.WebAppInitializer@12297d72]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/skillmanager/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/fanatik/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.SR1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/skillmanager/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMATION: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) für Kontext '/skillmanager' wird initialisiert.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:25 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMATION: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:26 AM net.bootsfaces.listeners.AddResourcesListener <clinit>
INFORMATION: net.bootsfaces.listeners.AddResourcesListener ready for use.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:27 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 9849 ms
Apr 25, 2015 12:10:34 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 25, 2015 12:10:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/skillmanager] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please provide the whole stacktrace and relevant code to analyze it,

Comment: Please fix managed beans annotations. `@ManagedBean`, 
`@Component`, `@ViewScoped` - `@Component` and `@ManagedBean` or `@Component` and `@ViewScoped` cannot be used together. If you have Spring manage your beans, annotations like `@ManagedProperty` will not work anymore as you are doing. Have either Spring or JSF managed your beans which you are interested in hereby not both of them.